# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or java.library.path for YARN / Hadoop2 Jobs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

i have a Hadoop `FileSystem` which is using native libraries with JNI.

Apparently i have to include the shared object independently of the currently executed job. But i can't find a way to tell Hadoop/Yarn where it should look for the shared object.

I had *partial success* with the following solutions, while starting the wordcount example with yarn.

- Setting `export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/path` when starting the resource- and the nodemanager.

  This helps with with the resource and the nodemanager, but the actual Job/Application fails. Printing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the `java.library.path` while executing the wordcount example yield the following result. What

  ```
  /logs/userlogs/application_x/container_x_001/stdout
  ...
  java.library.path : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x_001:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x
  ```
- Setting `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path"`

  This did help with some of the Jobs. The actual map/reduce job did work (at least i have the correct results), but the call did fail with the Error `no jni-xtreemfs in java.library.path`.

  Somehow the first application/job did work and shows

  ```
   /logs/userlogs/application_x/container_x_001/stdout
  ...
  java.library.path : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x_001:/path:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x_001:/path
  ```

  But the second and the rest did fail with:

  ```
   /logs/userlogs/application_x/container_x_002/stdout
  ...
  java.library.path : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x_002:/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH : /tmp/hadoop-u/nm-local-dir/usercache/u/appcache/application_x/container_x_002/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native
  ```

  The stacktrace for the later shows, that the error occured while executing `YarnChild`:

  ```
  2015-08-03 15:24:03,851 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jni-xtreemfs in java.library.path
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
      at org.xtreemfs.common.libxtreemfs.jni.NativeHelper.loadLibrary(NativeHelper.java:54)
      at org.xtreemfs.common.libxtreemfs.jni.NativeClient.<clinit>(NativeClient.java:41)
      at org.xtreemfs.common.libxtreemfs.ClientFactory.createClient(ClientFactory.java:72)
      at org.xtreemfs.common.libxtreemfs.ClientFactory.createClient(ClientFactory.java:51)
      at org.xtreemfs.common.clients.hadoop.XtreemFSFileSystem.initialize(XtreemFSFileSystem.java:191)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
  ```
- Supply the `libjni-xtreemfs.so` via the commandline argument `-files`

  This does work. I assume the .so is copied to the tmp directory. But this is no feasible solution, because it would require the users to supply the path to the .so on every call.

Does anybody now how i can globally set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the `java.library.path` or can suggest which configuration options i did probably miss? I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I have a similar issue, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately not. in the end we introduced a config parameter for our Hadoop FileSystem Implementation which points to the directory where the shared object can be found and did load it manually from there.
This is not perfect, but it does work and we don't have the users to provide the path to the .so in every call

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate you came back to answer.

Comment: @Tim and ae35 Can you explain how did you used config parameter for Hadoop FileSystem for loading shared object files...?

Comment: @GurinderbeerSingh I had this question in the context of Flink application I wrote and the solution was to add `-Djava.library.path=/path` argument directly to the application runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: in your **mapred-site.xml** put the following

```
<property>
<name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
<value>-Djava.library.path=$PATH_TO_NATIVE_LIBS</value>
</property>
```

Explanation:
The Job/Applications aren't executed by yarn rather than by a mapred (map/reduce) container, whoose configuration is controlled by the mapred-site.xml file. Specifying custom java parameters there causes that actual workers to spin with the correct path

Comment: uh. thanks? that helped?  I'm just a bit confused because i spent an hour looking for this and finally found the answer w no upvotes :)

Comment: The OP used different approach in order to solve the issue, but IMO (I'm bias) this is the correct approach and this is what we used before we moved to spark. The docs say "Usage of -Djava.library.path can cause programs to no longer function if hadoop native libraries are used. These values should instead be set as part of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the map / reduce JVM env using the mapreduce.map.env and mapreduce.reduce.env config settings." but I can't seem to find documentation regarding those parameters

Comment: heh, the only reason I'm doing this is because we are trying to use sqoop to copy data from RDBMS to HDFS to be then processed by Spark :)

Comment: if so, notice that the specified settings refer ONLY to hadoop map reduce tasks, not sure how scoop works, but for spark there are similar settings in the spark config file. as my original posts says - you need to find a way to set this on the JVM that runs the actual task

Comment: Yeah, Spark seems to have things working for me out of the box.  Sqoop is creating regular Hadoop mapreduce jobs, so your suggestion worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`mapreduce.map.env`** in your job or site configuration.

Usage is as follows:

```
<property>
             <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
             <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/my/libs</value>
</property>
```

Note: 
Hadoop docs encourage the use of `mapreduce.map.env` for this over `mapred.child.java.opts`. "Usage of -Djava.library.path can cause programs to no longer function if hadoop native libraries are used."